# Either grep or AWK are ereasing the content of processed stream

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Lets say i have a file like this:

```
ASI BEK BKG COE
0.00112000003 0.00003000000 -0.00001000000 0.00000000000
0.00170999998 -0.00009000000 -0.00008000000 0.00052000000
0.00089000002 -0.00003000000 -0.00028000001 0.00068000000
0.00031000000 0.00003000000 -0.00026000000 0.00057999999
0.00239000004 -0.00003000000 0.00004000000 0.00076999998
0.00000000000 0.00002000000 -0.00039000000 0.00050000002
0.00401999988 -0.00014000000 -0.00029000000 0.00046000001
0.00179999997 -0.00011000000 -0.00025000001 0.00044000000
0.00025000001 -0.00008000000 0.00004000000 0.00063000002
```

(Obviously it is larger, with longer records - but this sample is quite enough to understand the structure)

I want to simply use only digit-starting records (omit the title).
So i obviously do it by `grep ^[0-9]`.
BUT ! The output is perfectly nothing.
Because I need to use the file in general by columns I also use AWK.
And here is next odd thing. When I tried it like `cat file | grep ^[0-9] | awk '{ print }'`
it gaves me nothing. But when I set explicit column number in AWK (like `awk '{ print $1,$2...<and_so_on>}'` it works. I'd like to avoid using explicit column numbers since I don't understand what is wrong with this grep and also it is not the most beautiful solution.

Thanks in advance for any help. I hope it is simply such silly mistake made by me.

Comment: `grep ^[0-9] test.file | awk 1` works perfectly for me. what's wrong with that?

Comment: @hek2mgl - Seriously I have no idea - its not working on this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be dangerous not to use quoting with the shell. Some shells such as `csh` won't do what you think unless you quote the pattern `^[0-9]`. You should use single quotes here to ensure nothing is interpreted:

```
$ cat file | grep '^[0-9]' | awk '{print $0}'
0.00112000003 0.00003000000 -0.00001000000 0.00000000000
0.00170999998 -0.00009000000 -0.00008000000 0.00052000000
0.00089000002 -0.00003000000 -0.00028000001 0.00068000000
0.00031000000 0.00003000000 -0.00026000000 0.00057999999
0.00239000004 -0.00003000000 0.00004000000 0.00076999998
0.00000000000 0.00002000000 -0.00039000000 0.00050000002
0.00401999988 -0.00014000000 -0.00029000000 0.00046000001
0.00179999997 -0.00011000000 -0.00025000001 0.00044000000
0.00025000001 -0.00008000000 0.00004000000 0.00063000002
```

The `cat` and the `grep` are redundant here if you are going to use `awk`. `awk` can do patterning matching and read files all by itself:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/{print $0}' file
```

The default block in `awk` is `{print $0}` so we can also drop that:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]/' file
```

As you only want to skip over the first line in the file a better solution would be:

```
$ awk 'NR>1' file
```

---

Failing that it will most likely be a hidden character issues such a line endings. Try `dos2unix file` and see if that does the trick or inspect the file with a hex editor.

Comment: it works without quoting, at least in bash. Try : `grep ^[0-9] test.file | awk 1` .. So the OP's problem isn't reproducable for me. However, +1 for giving a lot of ways how to do it with `awk`

Comment: For other shells this will be an issue. You should **always** quoted to avoid any nasty surprises!

Comment: @hek2mgl - Yeah, when I made a test file it also works this way. But for some reasons it refuses to work with actual file.

Comment: @4rlekin if the file isn't toooo large, you could post it at pastebin.. Btw, before doing that, are you using `bash` as the shell?

Comment: If quoting doesn't solve the problem I suspect it's a hidden character issues such as line endings. Run `dos2unix` on the file and try again.

Comment: Yep! But strange thing - only last solution worked - the shortest one. All the others still gave null. Altought my problem is solved im still concerned about that so much solutions isnt working. copuld it be something with file formatting ?
@sudo_O it is file generated from bash as output from database under linux

Comment: @sudo_O Yep. I would in any case use `grep '^[0-9]' test.file` (quoted). I just wanted to point out, that I couldn't reproduce this special use case.

Comment: All I can do is speculate unless you post the actual file (at least truncated version) somewhere or a correct representation include any hidden characters (such as the hex).

Comment: Historical note (of no current significance that I'm aware of): the original Bourne shell used `^` (caret) instead of `|` (pipe) to mean 'pipe'. So once upon a long (long, long) time ago, `grep ^[0-9] file` would have meant 'run `grep` with no arguments and pipe the output to a program `[0-9]` (or the lowest single-digit program name in the current directory — possibly with higher numbered single-digit programs as extra arguments) with the argument `file`'. However, it's been decades since I used a shell with that feature. The UNIX 7th Edition manuals didn't note that behaviour.